# why UIColletionView with lazy var register cell class throws error?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

When I declare collection view with scope it does't registers cell class

```
lazy var flowLayout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {

        let f = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        f.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        f.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        f.minimumInteritemSpacing = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
        f.minimumLineSpacing = 5
        return f
    }()

    lazy var collection: UICollectionView = {

        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: self.flowLayout)
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        cv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.register(PreviewFilmsPosterCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        cv.backgroundColor = .black
        return cv
    }()
```

**It throws this error:**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to register a
>   cell class which is not a subclass of UICollectionViewCell

what is right solution?

**update**

but if I declare like so it works

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

        collectionview = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        collectionview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionview.dataSource = self
        collectionview.delegate = self
        collectionview.register(PreviewFilmsPosterCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        collectionview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionview.backgroundColor = .black

}
```

my **PreviewFilmsPosterCell Class**

```
class PreviewFilmsPosterCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let profileImageButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 50
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "profile_batman"), for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addViews()
    }

    func addViews(){

        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        addSubview(profileImageButton)

        profileImageButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        profileImageButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: And what is `PreviewFilmsPosterCell`? How is it declared? Not a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` I presume?

Comment: I have updated my question, if I declare in viewDidLoad it works. PreviewFilmsPosterCell is my cell class

Answer (score 0):

> `PreviewFilmsPosterCell` is **NOT** a subclass of UICollectionViewCell.

It must inherit UICollectionViewCell to be used in a UICollectionView

Make sure that your cell inherits properly

```
class PreviewFilmsPosterCell: UICollectionViewCell {...}
```

Comment: I have issue only with  **lazy var collection: UICollectionView**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
cv.register(PreviewFilmsPosterCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
```

this `PreviewFilmsPosterCell` class is not a subclass of  UICollectionViewCell

it must be

```
class PreviewFilmsPosterCell:UICollectionViewCell
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found my mistake in `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`

Comment: Can you please post the solution and accept the answer

Comment: it was just copy paste issue in `collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath)`